# JPA Hibernate Persistence exception [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've been trying to sort out a connection to my DB with JPA Hibernate and mysql, but for some reason, no matter what i try, when launching the tomcat server i get the same exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating     bean with name 'localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [core/JPAConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

This is my JPA config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("core.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class JPAConfig {

@Value("${db.jdbcURL}")
private String jdbcURL;

@Value("${db.user}")
private String user;

@Value("${db.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${db.generateDDL}")
private Boolean generateDDL;

@SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(Driver.class.getName());
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movierentaldb");
    dataSource.setUsername(System.getProperty("root"));
    dataSource.setPassword(System.getProperty("mdie1767"));
    dataSource.setInitialSize(2);
    dataSource.setMaxActive(5);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(generateDDL);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    factory.setPackagesToScan("core.model");

    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject();
}



@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager(){
    return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
}

@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return manager;
}

@Bean
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){
    return  new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(){
    GuavaCacheManager guavaCacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager();
    guavaCacheManager.setCacheBuilder(CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(2, TimeUnit.HOURS));
    return guavaCacheManager;
}
```

}

At this point i can't think of anything else to try..any help is much obliged

Edit: This is the entire stacktrace

```
23-May-2016 13:05:10.267 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
23-May-2016 13:05:10.444 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
23-May-2016 13:05:15.333 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [core/JPAConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4732)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5194)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/108265094.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    at core.JPAConfig.localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(JPAConfig.java:94)
    at core.JPAConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2bcf261.CGLIB$localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$1(<generated>)
    at core.JPAConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2bcf261$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$901863a2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355)
    at core.JPAConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2bcf261.localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTable(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.getTableInformation(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.performMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO))
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:43)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1683)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:656)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:349)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 92 more

23-May-2016 13:05:15.379 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Error:(7, 24) java: package org.gjt.mm.mysql does not exist
```

Comment: can you share entire stack(error) trace.

Comment: check your config, this could the reason `System.getProperty("root")`..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The issue is that you are not able to get a connection to MYSQL database and hence it is throwing an error saying that cannot build a session factory.**

Please see the error below:

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

which points to `username` not getting `populated`.

**Please recheck system properties**

```
dataSource.setUsername(System.getProperty("root"));
```

some packages seems to be missing as well pointing to a dependency issue:

```
package org.gjt.mm.mysql does not exist
```

Please run a `mvn dependency:tree` command to check for dependencies

Comment: After compiling, packaging and installing again the maven parent project, i managed to run a dependency:tree which solved my deps. Also the sys property was leading nowhere so i hardcoded the precise url string. Now it deploys without problems. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error even when all the relevant dependencies were in place because I hadn't created the schema in MySQL.

I thought it would be created automatically but it wasn't. Although the table itself will be created, you have to create the schema.

Comment: Yes, all tables are created in the pass, and transaction type jta. This EJB module work right well in jboss 7 but I'm migrating it to wildfly 20.0.1 and now give me this error

Answer (score 1):

I found some issue about that kind of error

1. Database username or password not match in the mysql or other other database. Please set application.properties like this

# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database please let me know "mondolmislam@gmail.com"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstoreapiabc

# Username and secret
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Issue no 2.

Your local server has two database server and those database server conflict. this conflict like this **mysql server & xampp or lampp or wamp** server. Please one of the database like **mysql server** because **xampp or lampp server** automatically install **mysql server** on this machine

Comment: Hi, I'm using transaciton type JTA, and I can see in logs that connect and publish all routing of jndi, but in the end before server is started give me those error, I'm using Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Got this error due to a mistake in a named query.

Comment: How can you resolved it, all my model entities are logging is not mapped?

Comment: In my hibernate version (5.4.19.Final) the named queries are checked in the constructor of org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl around line 327. With a breakpoint there you get clear error messages if named query checking is enabled (which should be the default).

Answer (score 0):

This error occured to me when I tried to connect to a MariaDB database when I had

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

specified in my application.properties. I did not set it to any other value and thus a bad driver was used. I removed the explicit driver description from my application.properties and let spring figure out on its own which driver to use. This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had a semicolon at the end, and gave me this error.

Comment: semicolon at the end in witch file?