# Error in spring boot app Not able to start tomcat after adding entities and hibernate configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Im getting below error after adding hibernate configuration to my app and not able to start server. I had created entitity classes.

In below screenshot you can see in left panel there is a PrimaryAccount class exist in com.userfront.domain package

[image: see in left panel there PrimaryAccount class exist in com.userfront.domain package]

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2017-11-18
>   20:56:32.700 ERROR 8408 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
>   com.userfront.domain.PrimaryTransaction.PrimaryAccount references an
>   unknown entity: com.userfront.domain.PrimaryAccount

i have below code in primaryAccount entity class.

```
    package com.userfront.domain;

    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

    public class PrimaryAccount {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private int accountNumber;
        private BigDecimal accountBalance;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy ="primaryAccount", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<PrimaryTransaction> primaryTransaction;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getAccountNumber() {
            return accountNumber;
        }

        public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }

        public BigDecimal getAccountBalance() {
            return accountBalance;
        }

        public void setAccountBalance(BigDecimal accountBalance) {
            this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
        }

        public List<PrimaryTransaction> getPrimaryTransaction() {
            return primaryTransaction;
        }

        public void setPrimaryTransaction(List<PrimaryTransaction> primaryTransaction) {
            this.primaryTransaction = primaryTransaction;
        }

    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.userFront</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserFront</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>UserFront</name>
    <description>User front of a Online Banking Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OnlineBanking

spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Help me out in fixing this.

Edited:
I have updated PrimaryAccount class with @Entity annotation, still im having below error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown
>   target entity property:
>   com.userfront.domain.PrimaryTransaction.primaryAccount in
>   com.userfront.domain.PrimaryAccount.primaryTransaction

PrimaryTransaction.java

```
package com.userfront.domain;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class PrimaryTransaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Date date;
    private String description;
    private String type;
    private String status;
    private double amount;
    private BigDecimal availableBalance;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "primary_account_id")
    private PrimaryAccount PrimaryAccount;

    public PrimaryTransaction() {  }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAvailableBalance() {
        return availableBalance;
    }

    public void setAvailableBalance(BigDecimal availableBalance) {
        this.availableBalance = availableBalance;
    }
}
```

2nd Edit: Corrected PrimaryAccount class where 'primaryTransaction' was to there to 'PrimaryTransaction' which is class name.

```
@Entity
public class PrimaryAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private int accountNumber;
    private BigDecimal accountBalance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="PrimaryAccount", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<PrimaryTransaction> PrimaryTransaction;
```

Got below error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

3rd Edit:

Entire Stacktrace

```
 2017-11-18 23:35:11.538  WARN 12435 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-11-18 23:35:11.541  INFO 12435 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-11-18 23:35:11.551  INFO 12435 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-18 23:35:11.557 ERROR 12435 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.userfront.UserFrontApplication.main(UserFrontApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(appointment_list)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

4th Edit:
Appointment.java

```
package com.userfront.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Date date;
    private String location;
    private String description;
    private boolean confirmed;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isConfirmed() {
        return confirmed;
    }

    public void setConfirmed(boolean confirmed) {
        this.confirmed = confirmed;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Appointment [id=" + id + ", date=" + date + ", location=" + location + ", description=" + description
                + ", confirmed=" + confirmed + ", user=" + user + "]";
    }

}
```

User.java

```
package com.userfront.domain;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="userId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    private boolean enabled = true;

    private PrimaryAccount primaryAccount;
    private SavingsAccount savingsAccount;
    private List<Appointment> appointmentList;
    private List<Recipient> recipientList;
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public PrimaryAccount getPrimaryAccount() {
        return primaryAccount;
    }
    public void setPrimaryAccount(PrimaryAccount primaryAccount) {
        this.primaryAccount = primaryAccount;
    }
    public SavingsAccount getSavingsAccount() {
        return savingsAccount;
    }
    public void setSavingsAccount(SavingsAccount savingsAccount) {
        this.savingsAccount = savingsAccount;
    }
    public List<Appointment> getAppointmentList() {
        return appointmentList;
    }
    public void setAppointmentList(List<Appointment> appointmentList) {
        this.appointmentList = appointmentList;
    }
    public List<Recipient> getRecipientList() {
        return recipientList;
    }
    public void setRecipientList(List<Recipient> recipientList) {
        this.recipientList = recipientList;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userId=" + userId + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", firstname="
                + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + ", phone=" + phone + ", enabled="
                + enabled + ", primaryAccount=" + primaryAccount + ", savingsAccount=" + savingsAccount
                + ", appointmentList=" + appointmentList + ", recipientList=" + recipientList + "]";
    }


}
```

Comment: can u paste the full stack trace i am unable to see caused by:

Comment: u can see if your issue is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388271/jpa-hibernate-persistence-exception-persistenceunit-default-unable-to-build-h

Comment: Updated full stacktrace, I have read above question but its not related to my problem as we dont have a JPA config class here and also no where it says issue with the DB credentials in error.

Comment: Do u have a user table ? That has appointment list ? Can you share that entity that's where the problem is

Comment: basically i'm following a tutorial there what he explained is after creating all entities and just by running appliction it should create tablels in mysql db with respective entities, in my case im not abble to run server. if remove  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency from pom file im able to start server but no tables are not created. Updated User and Appointment entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not mapped [Entity Types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#categorization-entity) correctly in your `User` entity, you should add [Associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations) mapping to it:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    private PrimaryAccount primaryAccount;

    @ManyToOne
    private SavingsAccount savingsAccount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Appointment> appointmentList;

    @OneToMany // you may add [mappedBy] if it's bidirectional
    private List<Recipient> recipientList;

    ...
}
```

To avoid this kind of mapping exception, annotate all fields explicitly, and do not let the ORM use the default mapping.

**Note:**

I've spotted a potential [StackOverflowError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) while looking to `User.toString()` and `Appointment.toString()`, as both will call each other infinitely:

```
Appointment.toString() {...+ ", appointmentList=" + appointmentList...}` 

User.toString() {...", user=" + user + "]"...}
```

You should get rid one of them.

Comment: Thanks a ton! now able to start application and all tables are created by itself. where can i learn more about these mappings?

Comment: @SameerShaik there is no better than [Hibernate official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#domain-model), also you may have a look at this useful [blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

PrimaryAccount class is not annotated with @Entity annotation. That might be the issue.

Try

```
 @Entity
 public class PrimaryAccount {
```

In the Primary account class mappedBy = **primaryAccount** But the variable name in PrimaryTransaction class is **PrimaryTransaction** i.e. a capital P change it to small case such that it matches

that should solve

> nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:

```
public class PrimaryAccount {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="**primaryAccount**", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<PrimaryTransaction> primaryTransaction;
```

Comment: my bad i missed it but after adding it getting same error. Please refer to edited details.

Comment: Updated class name, got different error with "Hibernate SessionFactory". Please refer to edited details